# How to prevent click event if click starts on child div and ends on parent (Chrome bug)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-events

I am trying to prevent `click` event from firing on parent `<div>` if user starts `click` on child `<div>`, then moves mouse out of child `<div>` but not leaving parent `<div>` while still holding it down, and then releases on parent.

Both parent and child have jQuery `click` events assigned with `event.stopPropagation()`.

What is expected is that there is no `click` event fired at all if I release mouse outside the `<div>` I initially pressed mouse down.

At least this is how it works on Firefox and Safari works but not on Chrome.

Buttons work as they should, divs don't. Maybe there's some magic I could copy from buttons and apply to the div?

http://jsfiddle.net/zd7L68b2

```
<div class="outer">
    <button class="inner">
    </button>
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>

$('.outer').click(function(e){
    console.log('Clicked outer');
});

$('.outer').moused(function(e){
    console.log('Clicked outer');
});

$('.inner').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Clicked inner');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, all mouse events are detected by the browser whether we choose to access them or not.

To solve your problem, instead of monitoring `click` events, I would monitor `mousedown` and `mouseup` events separately. In my simple code snippet, a `boolean` variable named `innerClick` is toggled `true` if the `mousedown` event occurred inside the required target, but no other code is fired. In a separate `mouseup` listener, a conditional checks whether the mouse is released inside the required target AND whether the `innerClick` `boolean` is set `true` (indicating the last mousedown was made there too). The code you need to execute, or a call to a function block containing it, is placed inside that conditional. In my snippet, a call is made to `console.log()` to demonstrate specificity.

The `mouseup` listener has to also then toggle `innerClick` to `false`;

```js
let innerClick = false;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
  if (event.target.id == "red") {
    // mouse down on red box;
    innerClick = true;
  } // end if;
}); // end mousedown event

document.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {
 
   if (innerClick && event.target.id == "red") {
     //mouse up inside red;
     console.log("exclusively inside red");
     // call or place code for red click here;
   } else {
     console.log("nope!");
   } // end if-else;
   
  //reset innerClick boolean;
  innerClick = false;

}); // end mouseup event
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
}


.inner {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="yellow" class="container">
  <div id="red" class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Note the `mousedown` and `mouseup` listeners are set on `document` rather than the element. This has no computational overhead but allows limitless combinations of elements to be monitored in two simple code blocks (each with its own conditional block where the relevant code can be placed, or called from).

Tested and working in Chrome and Firefox. Another advantage of using core JS is wider, bug-free, support.

Answer (score 0):

You could try binding mousedown() if that would keep your functionality the way you want it:

http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

I tried it on your jsfiddle and it worked. However, you lose the full click, you get just the mousedown ("half" a click so to speak).

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zd7L68b2/4/

```
$('.inner').mousedown(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   console.log('Clicked inner');
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need the click event